# add another field to jason array through looping in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have added Computer Marks Manually But I have to add ComputerMarks Field through looping to use the given JSON Array which is AnotherSubject To Match The Student Name with JASON Array then Add ComputerMarks field to each student JASON File

```js
let Student1={
    Name:"Mark",
    MathMarks:80,
    EnglishMarks:75,
    ScienceMarks:63,
 }


let Student2={
    Name:"Bob",
    MathMarks:90,
    EnglishMarks:81,
    ScienceMarks:88,
 }


let Student3={
    Name:"Julia",
    MathMarks:88,
    EnglishMarks:87,
    ScienceMarks:89,
 }

let Student4={
    Name:"Anthony",
    MathMarks:60,
    EnglishMarks:64,
    ScienceMarks:61,
 }

 let AnotherSubject=[
 {name:'Mark', ComputersMarks:90},
 {name:'Anthony', ComputersMarks:70},
 {name:'Julia', ComputersMarks:88},
 {name:'Bob', ComputersMarks:81}]

StudentsArray=[Student1,Student2,Student3,Student4]

let StudentMarks={
    students:StudentsArray
}
Student1.ComputersMarks=90
 Student2.ComputersMarks=81
 Student3.ComputersMarks=88
 Student4.ComputersMarks=70
console.log(StudentMarks.students)
```

Comment: JSON is not a javascript object, it is just string representation inspired from Java Script Object structure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For-each over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: `JSON.stringify(StudentMarks.students)` will output JSON

Answer (score 0):

a possible way

```js
const
  Student1     = { Name: 'Mark',    MathMarks: 80, EnglishMarks: 75, ScienceMarks: 63 } 
, Student2     = { Name: 'Bob',     MathMarks: 90, EnglishMarks: 81, ScienceMarks: 88 } 
, Student3     = { Name: 'Julia',   MathMarks: 88, EnglishMarks: 87, ScienceMarks: 89 } 
, Student4     = { Name: 'Anthony', MathMarks: 60, EnglishMarks: 64, ScienceMarks: 61 } 
, StudentsList = [ Student1, Student2, Student3, Student4 ] 
, AnotherSubject = 
  [ { Name: 'Mark',    ComputersMarks: 90 } 
  , { Name: 'Anthony', ComputersMarks: 70 } 
  , { Name: 'Julia',   ComputersMarks: 88 } 
  , { Name: 'Bob',     ComputersMarks: 81 }
  ]

function addNewProp ( List, newRefs )
  {
  let [key,prop] = Object.keys( newRefs[0]) 
  List.forEach(el =>
    {
    let newP = newRefs.find(x=>x[key]===el[key] )
    if (newP) el[prop] = newP[prop]
    });
  }

addNewProp(StudentsList, AnotherSubject)

console.log('Student1 ->', JSON.stringify( Student1) )
console.log('Student2 ->', JSON.stringify( Student2) )
console.log('Student3 ->', JSON.stringify( Student3) )
console.log('Student4 ->', JSON.stringify( Student4) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this would be to use the power of reduce and map.

`Reduce` basically makes an Object from an Array and `Map` transforms each item of an array and return the new array.

Additionally, we use the spear syntax `...` to manipulate objects.

```
// Here we are converting [{name: '', marks: 1 }] into { name: marks }
const AnotherSubjectsMap = AnotherSubject.reduce((accu, curr) => ({ 
    ...accu,
    [curr.name]: curr.ComputersMarks
}), {});

let StudentsArray = [Student1, Student2, Student3, Student4]

// Here were are going through the array and adding an extra parameter
StudentsArray = StudentsArray.map(Student => ({ 
    ...Student, // This line means we are copying all keys of Student as it is
    ComputersMarks: AnotherSubjectsMap[Student.Name]
}));

let StudentMarks = {
    students: StudentsArray
}

console.log(StudentMarks.students)
```

```js
let Student1 = {
  Name: "Mark",
  MathMarks: 80,
  EnglishMarks: 75,
  ScienceMarks: 63,
}


let Student2 = {
  Name: "Bob",
  MathMarks: 90,
  EnglishMarks: 81,
  ScienceMarks: 88,
}


let Student3 = {
  Name: "Julia",
  MathMarks: 88,
  EnglishMarks: 87,
  ScienceMarks: 89,
}

let Student4 = {
  Name: "Anthony",
  MathMarks: 60,
  EnglishMarks: 64,
  ScienceMarks: 61,
}

let AnotherSubject = [{
    name: 'Mark',
    ComputersMarks: 90
  },
  {
    name: 'Anthony',
    ComputersMarks: 70
  },
  {
    name: 'Julia',
    ComputersMarks: 88
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    ComputersMarks: 81
  }
]

AnotherSubjectsMap = AnotherSubject.reduce((accu, curr) => ({
  ...accu,
  [curr.name]: curr.ComputersMarks
}), {});

StudentsArray = [Student1, Student2, Student3, Student4]

StudentsArray = StudentsArray.map(Student => ({
  ...Student,
  ComputersMarks: AnotherSubjectsMap[Student.Name]
}));

let StudentMarks = {
  students: StudentsArray
}

console.log(StudentMarks.students)
```

Comment: @MisterJojo updated the code and the snippet. I was trying to read `curr.Name` where it should've been `curr.name`.

Comment: the devil is in the details